# GlusterFs brick readonly

Tags: volume, databricks, glusterfs

I want to make old bricks of my gluster volume readonly and deleteonly once they are full and I expand my volume to add new bricks. I could find the feature.read-only option that sets the whole gluster volume readonly but no option to make only some bricks read only.